# Putting constantly "changing" text files into a list view

Tags: java, android, xml, list, layout

I'm trying to build a note app. My problem is to display text files (.txt) in a list on the mainpage. The list should show the title of the note and the content. But i dont know how to code the custom adapter.

The files get saved like this:

```
final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
final EditText note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);

String head = title.getText().toString();
String body = note.getText().toString();
String fullnote = body + "\n" + head;

try {
FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(head + ".txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
fo.write(fullnote.getBytes());
fo.write("\n".getBytes());
fo.write("\n".getBytes());
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now i want to load those files in a List View:

```
String[] listItems = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "etc.",};
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainpage_list);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
```

"Item 1", "Item 2" and "etc." are just Placeholders.

I want the file-name to be the Item and the content of the file to be the subitem.
I have never worked with ListViews and Adapters before, so i am kinda clueless.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for sweet simplicity, I would suggest:

- Make each note a separate file.
- Make the file name the note's title (be sure to clean this so people don't put things like ".." in there which manipulate the path).

That would be very easy to implement and deal with.  If you need to do more fancy things (like keep track of history, for example), then you'll need to revisit the structure.  But based on your requirements, I would go with the above.

Comment: First of all thank you. I still don't know how to make a list without hardcoding it. So how would you do it?

Comment: It can't be hardcoded because the title is obviously variable by the user.

Comment: Sounds like you want: `File[] files = new File("/path/to/your/notes/").listFiles();`  That will give you an array of File objects you can work with.